# Declaration name conflicts with built-in global identifier 'globalThis'

Tags: typescript

I am getting the error "Declaration name conflicts with built-in global identifier 'globalThis'" for the following code

```
interface globalThis {
    whatever: string
}
```

Why can I do

```
 interface Window {
    whatever: string
 }
```

but not do the same for globalThis?

Comment: Because you can only extend interfaces. `globalThis` is not an interface, it is a built-in namespace that is injected at compilation time. See [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29332) where it was added

Answer (score 2):

The identifier `globalThis` is already taken by some (built-in) value; upon closer inspection, this value is declared in TypeScript as a namespace. Since the [rules of merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#basic-concepts) don't allow merging interfaces and namespace, you get this error.